# Javascript - Extract css classes from string

Tags: javascript, css, string

I'm trying to create a dynamic css theme and in order to do that I need to extract all css variables from a string, collected from a stylesheet record. And then replace the existing values of the root variables with the ones returned from the stylesheet.

I'm mainly a CSS guy and my javascript knowledge and/or regex knowledge isn't super great. My coworker is already on holiday leave so I thought I'd ask this wonderful community :)

The stylesheet has contents that look something like this:

```
// ****************************
// DYNAMIC STYLESHEET THEME
// ****************************
:root {
--var-body-bg: red;
--var-text-color: green;
--var-button-primary: orange;
}
```

So, I need each variable because I plan to run them through this function that essentially replaces the values:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--var-body-bg', 'red');
```

I'm not even sure it'll work, but in order to even get started, I have to figure out a way to extract these values from the string.

Edit: Found a short snippet :)

```
var parseCssRules = function (cssText) {
    var tokenizer = /\s*([a-z\-]+)\s*:\s*((?:[^;]*url\(.*?\)[^;]*|[^;]*)*)\s*(?:;|$)/gi,
    obj = {},
    token;
    while ( (token=tokenizer.exec(cssText)) ) {
       obj[token[1].toLowerCase()] = token[2];
    }
   return obj;
};
```

Comment: How about using an actual CSS parser? E.g. https://github.com/csstree/csstree or maybe even postcss. You can then walk the generated AST and extract the data you are interested in ([AST for your example](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/791e756da4b0c585e0c33a49b01939f2/42ddc3e0cf5606673f9456f535272ee5bf76d1e0)).

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking at these. But I don't want to include a dependency, cause I really only need a super simple parser that gives me an array with each variable 

"--var-varibable" : "value;"

I plan to have this run in a single lightweight js include

Comment: how about something more simple like `^([a-z-]+)\s*\:\s*([^;]+);?$` or with named groups `^(?<key>[a-z-]+)\s*\:\s*(?<value>[^;]+);?$` ?